# Assign list to a key within a chart

Tags: templates, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Deployment.yaml

```
...
env: {{ .Values.env}}
...
```

Values.yaml:

```
env:
- name: "DELFI_DB_USER"
  value: "yyy"
- name: "DELFI_DB_PASSWORD"
  value: "xxx"
- name: "DELFI_DB_CLASS"
  value: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
- name: "DELFI_DB_URL"
  value: "jdbc:sqlserver://dockersqlserver:1433;databaseName=ddbeta;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false"
```

feels like I'm missing something obvious.
linter says: ok
template says:

> env: [map[name:DELFI_DB_USER value:yyy] map[name:DELFI_DB_PASSWORD
>   value:xxx] map[name:DELFI_DB_CLASS value:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>   map[value:jdbc:mysql://dockersqlserver.{{ .Release.Namespace
>   }}.svc.cluster.local:3306/ddbeta\?\&amp\;useSSL=true\&amp\;requireSSL=false
>   name:DELFI_DB_URL]]

upgrade says:

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on
>   xxx/templates/deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml:
>   line 35: found unexpected ':'

solution:

```
env:
{{- range .Values.env }}
- name: {{ .name | quote }}
  value: {{ .value | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current Go template expansion will give output which is not YAML:

```
env: {{ .Values.env}}
```

becomes:

```
env: env: [Some Go type stuff that isn't YAML]...
```

The Helm Go template needs to loop over the keys of the source YAML dictionary.
This is described in the [Helm docs](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/#looping-with-the-range-action).

The correct Deployment.yaml is:

```
...
env:
{{- range .Values.env }}
  - name: {{ .name | quote }}
    value: {{ .value | quote }}
{{- end }}
...
```

Comment: but I need to assign it to the env: key?

Comment: The Go templates are dumber than that, you're just asking it for a find and replace here. The expanded template needs to be valid YAML. You should be able to see the full expanded yaml if you pass in `--debug` to helm.

Comment: ok, but it still produces that weird thing from my question: `[map bla-bla-bla]`, instead of yaml

Comment: Right so looks like you need to fix the Go template to loop over the YAML keys

Comment: Look at https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/#looping-with-the-range-action. I've updated the answer but I haven't run it

Answer (score 1):

Helm includes [undocumented `toYaml` and `toJson` template functions](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/pkg/engine/engine.go#L80); either will work here (because valid JSON is valid YAML).  A shorter path could be

```
env: {{- .Values.env | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
```

Note that you need to be a little careful with the indentation, particularly if you're setting any additional environment variables that aren't in that list.  In this example I've asked Helm to indent the YAML list two steps more, so additional environment values need to follow that too

```
env: {{- .Values.env | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
  - name: OTHER_SERVICE_URL
    value: "http://other-service.default.svc.cluster.local"
```

Comment: weird. I tried toyaml it didn't work. I'll try again thanks